# html css images with more image

Tags: html, css, image, slice

If I have an image like this (for example):

[image: http://www.tiscali.it/v007/img/el.v004.png]
<sub>(source: [tiscali.it](http://www.tiscali.it/v007/img/el.v004.png))</sub>

with more background element for my web site, how can extract a single element with css properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the "CSS Sprite" method. It means that you need to create an element block width specified `width` and `height`, then give it a `background-image` along with `background-position` and `backgorund-url`, then hide everything that goes out of the box `overflow:hidden;`

reference to this tutorial for example, it's well explained there: [CSS Sprite link](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS sprites
http://www.google.de/search?q=css+sprites

Example with your image
http://jsfiddle.net/qxVf8/

---

### html

```
<div class="sprite sprite1">
</div>
```

---

### css

```
​.sprite {
    background: url(http://www.tiscali.it/v007/img/el.v004.png) 0 0 transparent;
}
.sprite1 {
    width: 79px;
    height: 28px;
    background-position: -0px -305px;
    border: 1px solid magenta;
}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the css sprites technique](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) for that.